# Is there a "children" method in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, data-modeling, parent-child, parent

When entities with a parent are created, they can always reference this parent by [calling the `parent()` method](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_parent) in Python.

Does the parent have a corresponding `children()` method? I didn't see one in the docs. If not, is there an equivalent query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can query for objects with a given ancestor.  Check out the [`ancestor()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_ancestor) method on the query object, or [`ANCESTOR IS`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) if you prefer GQL.

Comment: Bear in mind that this returns everything that has the target entity as an ancestor, not just as its parent.